# Formatting dictionary categories and altering their locations

Tags: python, database, dictionary, for-loop, format

How can I write a code where it concatenates option 3 and option 4 and alters the
Outcomes dictionary to be the expected Output. The `Concatinating_variables` list shows the two values within the list that are to be concatenated together, option 3 comes before option 4 meaning that the function will arrange the option 3 values before option 4. How would I be able to do this and get the expected output below? Code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

Outcomes = {....}
Coacatinating_variables = ['option 3', 'option 4']
```

Dictionary

```
Outcomes = {
    'Values':{
        'First': {
            'option 1': np.array([12,345,5412]),
            'option 2': np.array([2315,32,1]),
            'option 4': {'row 4': np.array([232,3,1]),
                         'row 5': np.array([3,4,5]),
                         'row 6': np.array([15,6,12])}
        },
        'Second': {
            'option 1': np.array([1,4,5]),
            'option 2': np.array([5,6,3]),
            'option 3': {'row 1': np.array([-5,3,1]),
                         'row 2': np.array([4,4,12]),
                         'row 3': np.array([67,6,5])}        
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
Outcomes = {
    'Values':{
        'First': {
            'option 1': np.array([12,345,5412]),
            'option 2': np.array([2315,32,1]),
            'option 4': {'row 1': np.array([-5,3,1]),
                         'row 2': np.array([4,4,12]),
                         'row 3': np.array([67,6,5]),
                         'row 4': np.array([232,3,1]),
                         'row 5': np.array([3,4,5]),
                         'row 6': np.array([15,6,12])}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
Outcomes = {
    'Values':{
        'First': {
            'option 1': np.array([12,345,5412]),
            'option 2': np.array([2315,32,1]),
            'option 4': {'row 4': np.array([232,3,1]),
                         'row 5': np.array([3,4,5]),
                         'row 6': np.array([15,6,12])}
        },
        'Second': {
            'option 1': np.array([1,4,5]),
            'option 2': np.array([5,6,3]),
            'option 3': {'row 1': np.array([-5,3,1]),
                         'row 2': np.array([4,4,12]),
                         'row 3': np.array([67,6,5])}        
        }
    }
}


extra_entry = Outcomes.pop('Second')
Outcomes['Values']['First']['option 4'] = {
    **Outcomes['Values']['First']['option 4'], **extra_entry['option 3']
}
print(Outcomes)
```